# Shopify Theme Development | Creating a 're-order' link for previous orders | Unable to chain multiple ID:quantity query strings

Tags: themes, shopify, query-string, cart

I am using Shopify and creating a re-order button within the file named order.liquid.

while trying to create the re-order button I have had a moderate level of success.

The script I attach does indeed add the items to the cart that were previously ordered. However, I have tried without adding the quantity (just adds 1 of each). Without the [] after the &quantity**HERE**= (just adds two of each even if it was previously only one item bought).

Heres the code that creates my half-working URL:

```
{% assign line_items_string = '/cart/' %}
{% for line_item in order.line_items %}

    {% if forloop.first == true %}

        {% assign line_items_string = line_items_string | append: 'add?id[]=' %}
        {% assign line_items_string = line_items_string | append: line_item.variant_id %}
        {% assign line_items_string = line_items_string | append: '&quantity[]=' %}
        {% assign line_items_string = line_items_string | append: line_item.quantity %}

    {% else %}

        {% assign line_items_string = line_items_string | append: '&id[]=' %}
        {% assign line_items_string = line_items_string | append: line_item.variant_id %}
        {% assign line_items_string = line_items_string | append: '&quantity[]=' %}
        {% assign line_items_string = line_items_string | append: line_item.quantity %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

<a href="{{ line_items_string }}" class="reorder-link">Re-order</a>
```

I am unable to get it to add the correct amount of items per line item even though the URL appears correct:

```
/cart/add?id[]=16220586868785&quantity[]=3&id[]=16220587360305&quantity[]=6&id[]=16220587622449&quantity[]=4&id[]=16221376479281&quantity[]=11&id[]=16221376348209&quantity[]=2&id[]=16221063938097&quantity[]=1&id[]=16221393682481&quantity[]=2
```

The fact the string ends with quantity 2 and will then add 2 of each item suggests it only uses the last declaration of quantity when dealing with the link. Therefore there must be a separator that can be used to distinguish between line items.

**What is the separator that would go between each line items addition to the query string please? What goes after?**

```
add?id[]=16220586868785&quantity[]=3**HERE**
```

I have tried using a `,` but admittedly this looks out of place followed by an `&`.

### Edit

To help describe further what I have tried.

I am able to use the format ID:quantity if I:

1. want to go straight to checkout, the format is ID:quantity,ID:quantity.. so on.
2. only wish to add one item of a certain quantity to cart using add?ID:Quantity.

I need to know how to chain multiple to only add to cart. I don't know the separator (that is a comma when pushing straight to checkout).

Answer (score 0):

Using permalinks to re-order things is always the ID:quantity. Have you tried that?

Comment: I am able to use that format if I 1) want to go straight to checkout, the format is ID:quantity,ID:quantity.. so on. 2) only wish to add one item of a certain quantity to cart using add?ID:Quantity. I need to know how to chain multiple to only add to cart but I don't know the separator (that is comma when pushing straight to checkout). Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider implementing this using jquery or javascript. You can create an ajax post using the `cart/add.js` call described here: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#add-to-cart